# How to set the language of the reportviewer toolbar of VS 2010?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I am making a windows form application using Visual Studio 2010.

I am using ReportViewer tool to show my RDLC report. The header of the toolbar is coming in English no matter what the currentUI or the current culture is as I am also Explicitly setting it as French but still its coming only in English, I am trying to display the toolbar according to the region of the Destination computer in which my application will run.

Till now I have add these lines to set the cultures explicitly during the loading of my windows form.

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");`

and tested it using

`MessageBox.Show(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.ToString());`

which provide me with the outcome (fr-FR).

Any assistance or guidance will be very helpful thank you.

Comment: It will be great if you can share the piece of you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the ReportViewer Language Pack (this is probably the version you need [Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2010 Language Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20884)).

Also have a look at [How to localize the ReportViewer control in ASP.NET 2.0](http://blog.bennedik.de/2006/08/how-to-localize-reportviewer-control.html) as it provides more information of localizing the report viewer.

Perhaps this article can also help you: [Customizing and Localizing Microsoft ReportViewer .NET - An exact solution.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17609/Customizing-and-Localizing-Microsoft-ReportViewer)

Comment: Thanku :-) you saved my day, great article also

Answer (score 1):

On `Windows Forms` you can install the correct language pack on every client that uses your application (i.e.: link to [italian language pack](http://www.microsoft.com/it-it/download/details.aspx?id=20884)).

On `ASP.NET` you can implement the [IReportViewerMessages2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportviewermessages2.aspx) interface to provide custom localization of the `ReportViewer` control user interface.